# Given an address, how to find travel time to multiple predetermined locations

Tags: google-maps

I am looking at potential houses to buy and for each one I would like to know the travel times to key locations (e.g. my workplace, my spouse's workplace, our children's schools).

Although I can type each route into Google Maps individually I would like a way to just type in the one address (of potential new house) and have it tell me the travel time to those other locations, ideally also with the ability to specify the time of day that I would be travelling.

Is there a web app that has this functionality?

Comment: Does this help? http://findthebestroute.com/RouteFinder.html

Comment: Not really, as I want to know the distance from a given location (potential house) to a number of different locations. It's not helpful to know the fastest way to order travel times is to go from home to my workplace and then to my children's schools (since I would still need to go back to my workplace after dropping off the children).